# Error:value.pos[i] is undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like this(this is one of many):

```
T1 = [
{
    tipo:"m",
    pos: [
        [0,0]
    ]

    },{
    tipo:"b",
    pos: [
        [0,0.223,0.1,0.5,0.11,0.5]
    ]
    },
    {
    tipo:"m",
    pos: [
        [0,0]
    ]
    }
    ]
```

and then I verify what is the type and then draw depending on what is.

```
function caminho(c, a) {
c.beginPath();
a.forEach(function(value, i) {
if (value.tipo === "m") {
  c.moveTo(value.pos[i][0], value.pos[i][1]);
  console.log(value.pos);
  } else if (value.tipo === "l") {
       value.pos.forEach(function(pos, j) {
          c.lineTo(pos[0], pos[1]);
    });

    }
    else if(value.tipo === "q") {
      value.pos.forEach(function(pos,j) {
          c.quadraticCurveTo(pos[0], pos[1], pos[2], pos[3]);
    });
}
    else if(value.tipo === "a") {
    value.pos.forEach(function(pos,j) {
        c.arc(pos[0],pos[1],pos[2],pos[3],pos[4]);
    });
}
   else if(value.tipo === "b") {
    value.pos.forEach(function(pos,j) {
        c.bezierCurveTo(pos[0],pos[1],pos[2],pos[3],pos[4],pos[5]);
    })
}
 });
  c.closePath();
  }
```

the problem is because I'm getting that error, but if i remove the last type of "m" from T1 function it works fine.
What I want to do with the T1 is this basically but using the struct I'm using with array:

```
c2d.beginPath(); 
    c2d.moveTo(0, 0);
    c2d.bezierCurveTo(0,0.223,0.1,0.5,0.11,0.5);
    c2d.moveTo(0, 0);
c2d.closePath();
```

Comment: Just a guess,seems instead of `value.tipo` it should be `value.type`

Comment: yes but the problem is not that, i just changed now the tipo to type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `i` variable presents index of item in your array. So it will be 0, 1, 2, ...

But your `pos` array just has one element inside as you put example in question. So replace this loc from

```
c.moveTo(value.pos[i][0], value.pos[i][1]);
```

To

```
c.moveTo(value.pos[0][0], value.pos[0][1]);
```

Full code here

```js
function caminho(c, a) {
  c.beginPath();
  a.forEach(function(value, i) {
    if (value.tipo === "m") {
      c.moveTo(value.pos[0][0], value.pos[0][1]);
      console.log(value.pos);
    } else if (value.tipo === "l") {
      value.pos.forEach(function(pos, j) {
        c.lineTo(pos[0], pos[1]);
      });
    } else if (value.tipo === "q") {
      value.pos.forEach(function(pos, j) {
        c.quadraticCurveTo(pos[0], pos[1], pos[2], pos[3]);
      });
    } else if (value.tipo === "a") {
      value.pos.forEach(function(pos, j) {
        c.arc(pos[0], pos[1], pos[2], pos[3], pos[4]);
      });
    } else if (value.tipo === "b") {
      value.pos.forEach(function(pos, j) {
        c.bezierCurveTo(pos[0], pos[1], pos[2], pos[3], pos[4], pos[5]);
      });
    }
  });
  c.closePath();
}
```